# MATLAB Subplot Make Figure Larger

Tags: matlab, plot, size, figure

I am plotting two maps next to each other using subplot. However, now, the image is turning out like this:
[image]

Is there any way to make the map part of the image larger? I would like to plot the maps side by side, by in this image, the resolution is low and the size is small.

```
%% Graph one site at a time
nFrames = 6240; % Number of frames. 
for k = 94:nFrames 
    h11 = subplot(1,2,1); % PM2.5
    % Map of conterminous US
    ax = figure(1);
    set(ax, 'visible', 'off', 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);     
    ax = usamap('conus');
    set(ax,'Position',get(h11,'Position'));
    delete(h11);
    states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
        'Selector',...
        {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
    faceColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon',...
        {'INDEX', [1 numel(states)], 'FaceColor', 'none'}); % NOTE - colors are random
    geoshow(ax, states, 'DisplayType', 'polygon', ...
        'SymbolSpec', faceColors)
    framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off

    hold on

    % Plot data
    scatterm(ax,str2double(Lat_PM25{k})', str2double(Lon_PM25{k})', 25, str2double(data_PM25{k})', 'filled'); 

    % Colorbar
    caxis([5 30]);
    h = colorbar;
    ylabel(h,'ug/m3');

    % Title
    title(['PM2.5 24-hr Concentration ', datestr(cell2mat(date_PM25(k)), 'mmm dd yyyy')]); 

    %%%%
    h22 = subplot(1,2,2); % O3
    % Map of conterminous US
    ax2 = usamap('conus');
    set(ax2,'Position',get(h22,'Position'));
    delete(h22);
    states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,...
        'Selector',...
        {@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
    faceColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon',...
        {'INDEX', [1 numel(states)], 'FaceColor', 'none'}); % NOTE - colors are random
    geoshow(ax2, states, 'DisplayType', 'polygon', ...
        'SymbolSpec', faceColors)
    framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off

   hold on

    % Plot data
    scatterm(ax2,str2double(Lat_O3{k})', str2double(Lon_O3{k})', 25, str2double(data_O3{k})'*1000, 'filled'); 
hold on

    % Colorbar
    caxis([10 90]);
    h = colorbar;
    ylabel(h,'ppb');

    % Title
    title(['O3 MDA8 Concentration ', datestr(cell2mat(date_O3(k)), 'mmm dd yyyy')]); % Title changes every daytitle(str);

    % Capture the frame
    mov(k) = getframe(gcf); % Makes figure window pop up

     % Save as jpg
    eval(['print -djpeg map_US_' datestr(cell2mat(date_PM25(k)),'yyyy_mm_dd') '_PM25_24hr_O3_MDA8.jpg']);

    clf

end

close(gcf)
```

Comment: Could you simply make the figure larger? `figure('Position', [10 10 1000 1000])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/12/21/figure-margins-subplot-spacings-and-more/#1) has many great examples of FileExchange scripts dealing with size of subplots.

[subplot_tight](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30884-controllable-tight-subplot) works very well and makes the subplots larger. Instead of writing in `subplot(1,2,1)`, use `subplot_tight(1,2,1)`

Answer (score 0):

To change the amount of space the data occupies in the figure, you can use this command:

```
set(gca,'Position',[0.1 .1 0.75 0.85])
```

You'll have to play with the numbers a bit, to get things look nice. Note that Matlab rescales everything when you resize the figure window, so the optimal numbers depend on the window size you want to use.

On the other hand, you want to make the map bigger in comparison to the colorbar. You cannot make it without changing your window size, because your maps are already as *high* as the color bars. I would suggest to:

1. <s>Set caxis to the same range in both plots.</s>
2. <s>Remove the colorbar on the left one.</s>
3. Increase the height of your figure window to make the maps occupy as much width as possible.
4. Put the two images nicelye side by side using the command above.

For more information, see [Matlab Documentation on Axes Properties](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html).

**Example:**

```
% Default dimenstions
figure
x = 1:.1:4;
y = x;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

subplot(1,2,1)
h = pcolor(X, Y, sin(X).*cos(Y)*2);
set(h, 'EdgeAlpha', 0);
axis square
colorbar

subplot(1,2,2)
h = pcolor(X, Y, sin(Y).*cos(X));
set(h, 'EdgeAlpha', 0);
axis square
colorbar


% adjust dimensions
subplot(1,2,1)
set(gca, 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.3 0.85])

subplot(1,2,2)
set(gca, 'Position', [0.55 0.1 0.3 0.85])
```

Comment: How can I increase the height of my figure window? For the command you gave above, can you tell me which line in my code I should be replacing? I assume I would need to do the same for both subplots? I can't remove a color bar or set the range the same because the two parameters are measured in different units.

Comment: You're right about the color bars, I did not pay enough attention. Unfortunately, I cannot run your code since I do not have the Map Toolbox. If you simplify it—which is a good practice in general when asking questions here—to require just the basic Matlab, I can try to help you further. Also see the documentation that I linked in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but could you tell me which parts are essential if I were to simplify the code? I guess the title and colorbar parts wouldn't be necessary, but how much of the mapping part is?

Comment: I have added an example code. Check if it clarifies the things. Run it till "adjust dimensions" first, and then execute the last lines.

Comment: MATLAB said 'There is no 'EdgeAlpha' property in the 'hggroup' class.' Should I be using `ALim'?

Comment: @shizishan, this code works as given above in my Matlab R2012b. However, you do not need the `set(h...)` lines, they are just for illustration. So you do not need `alim` either.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar -> scaling subplots in a figure a bit more up. Important for me though, was to maintain the aspect ratio that I've set before.

Enhancing the answer from @texnic in order to not have to set the values manually, one might use the following:

```
scale = 1.1;                % Subplot scale

subplot(1,2,1)
% Your plotting here ...

pos = get(gca, 'Position'); % Get positions of the subplot [left bottom width height]
set(gca, 'Position', [pos(1) pos(2) pos(3)*scale pos(4)*scale]); % Scale width and height
```

Understanding this, one can also easily implement a parametric move of the subplot.